# oracle: For update select first 10 rows

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have an `ITEM` table with one of the column as `CREATED_DATE`. In a clustered enviroment, many copies of services will pick items from this table and process it. Each service should pick the oldest 10 items from the ITEM table.

I am able to select top 10 rows using this in a Stored Procedure:

```
select * from (
    select  item_id, row_number() over (order by CREATED_DATE) rownumber
    FROM item )
where rownumber < 11
```

Since many service should use this, I am using `select ... for update` to update the rows as "processing". But the below `FOR UPDATE` statement, fails for the above select statement with error "ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."

```
OPEN items_cursor FOR
**select Statement**
FOR UPDATE;
```

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DCookie's answer doesn't solve multisession processing (it's just FOR UPDATE syntax fix). If you won't manipulate rownumber range, every instance of service if going to select for update the same rows. If you execute that_for_update_select in two sessions, the second one is going to wait until first finishes the transaction. Parallel processing will be an illusion.

I would consider efficient bulk processing together with `for update skip locked` approach. My answer below:

```
declare 
  con_limit constant number default 10;
  cursor cItems is
    select i.item_id, i.created_date
    from item i
    order by i.created_date
    for update skip locked;
  type t_cItems is table of cItems%rowtype;
  tItems t_cItems;
begin
  open cItems;
  while true loop
    fetch cItems bulk collect into tItems limit con_limit;
    -- processing tItems
    exit when tItems.count < con_limit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Possible long transaction could be a disadvantage. Consider using Oracle Streams Advanced Queuing (DBMS_AQ) as an alternative to this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for your situation?

```
SELECT *
  FROM item
 WHERE (item_id,created_date) IN
       (SELECT item_id,created_date
          FROM (SELECT item_id, created_date
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_date) rownumber
                  FROM item)
         WHERE rownumber < 11)
```

Comment: Yes. It works.  Thank you very much.  I have indexes on created_date and item_id.  Is there anything else i can do to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skip locked` and a counter to achieve this, as long as you don't necessarily need each session to get contiguous rows. For example:

```
declare
    l_cursor sys_refcursor;
    l_name all_objects.object_name%type;
    l_found pls_integer := 0;
begin
    open l_cursor for
        select  object_name
        from all_objects
        order by created
        for update skip locked;

    loop
        fetch l_cursor into l_name;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_fetches || ':' || l_name);
        if l_cursor%found then
            l_found := l_found + 1;
            -- dbms_lock.sleep(1);
        end if;
        exit when l_cursor%notfound or l_found = 10;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

If you run this simultaneously from two sessions they'll get different objects (though you may need to enable the call to `dbms_lock.sleep` inside the `found` block to make it slow enough to be visible).

According to [this post](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/02/for-update-skip-locked.html), when using `skip locked` the selected rows aren't locked until they're fetched, and any rows locked by another session after the cursor is opened are just ignored.

Comment: In the same post, Rob also explained that it does not help to improve performance.

Comment: @lk_zeif - I was only looking for something that might work at this stage, and not really thinking about performance; but it does allow multiple sessions to run simultaneously at least, without tripping over each other. There'll be some impact from them all hitting the same table, of course, but they don't block each other - they don't queue up and run in series.

Comment: @lk_zeif - the performance info was in [this post](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/12/parallellism-in-skip-locked-scenario.html), which you linked to in another question; I don't remember reading that one before. I didn't notice delays from two sessions, but then in my trivial example it was probably lost in the noise from the sleep. Definitely something to consider and check for though, if attempting this approach, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ik_zelf - er, apologies for mangling your username in both comments, and not noticing in time to edit either of them *8-)

Comment: don't worry, be happy, I can live with that. From errors we learn.